# SSIS - Execute task in foreach loop only once

Tags: foreach, ssis

I need some help with the following issue:

Inside a foreach loop, I have a Data Flow Task that reads each file from the collection folder. If it fails while proccesing a certain file, that file is copied to an error folder (using a file system task called "Copy Work to Error").

I would like to set up a Send Email Task that warns me if there were any files sent to the error folder during the package execution. 
I could easily add this task after the "Copy Work to Error" task, but if there are many files that fail the Data Flow Task, my inbox would get filled.

Instead, I would like  the Send Mail Task only once (after the foreach loop completes) only if the "Copy Work to Error" task was executed at least once. Is there any way I could achieve that?

Thanks,

Ovidiu

Comment: What details do you want in the email? Only that processing failed for one or more files, or the file names and so on?

Comment: A simple warning message should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using just a boolean variable say IsError created outside the scope of the for each loop with default value as False. You can set this to True immediately after the success of Copy Work to Error task using an expression task(SSIS 2012) or an Execute SQL task. And finally your Send Mail task would be connected to the For Each loop with the precedence constraint set as the Expression  - isError.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use expression tasks (SSIS 2008), but I think I will go with your second suggestion (using an Execute SQL task), since I find it to be the easiest one to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way that I can think of:

1. Create an integer variable, `@Total` outside the `ForEach` container and set it to 0.
2. Create an integer variable, `@PerIteration` inside the `ForEach` container.
3. Add a `Script Task` as an event handler to the `File System Task`. This task should increment `@Total` by `@PerIteration`.
4. Add your `SendMail` task after the `ForEach` container. In the precedence constraint, set type to `Expression`, and specify the condition `@Total > 0`. This should ensure that your task is triggered only if the `File System Task` was executed in the loop at least once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not familliar with using scripts, so any additional tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A script is either C# or VB.Net code. You can deal with variables and even SSIS objects from a script as well as do other stuff like in a normal program.

Answer (score 0):

When the error happens, create a record in a table with the information you would like to include in the email - e.g.
1. File that failed with full path
2. the specific error
3. date/time

Then at the end of the package, send a consolidated email. This way, you have a central location to turn to in case you want to revisit the issue, or if the email is lost/not delivered.

If you need implementation help, please revert back.